# Proper way to Import data from Access to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ms-access

I'm asking for the proper way, in SQL Server's T-SQL (I think that's what it is) code or using another language, to import data from a Microsoft Access MDB Database into a new SQL Server Database.

Now, typically I would just import it in. The problem is I'm writing a .SQL script (I could use another technology if needed) to do all this leg work as this will need to be done fairly regularly. Likely at least once a week, for about 5 months in the year.

To digress a tad, I had wanted to implement a single database and distinguish separate source database using something like a `DatabaseID` field, but the powers that be overthrew me there.

I was previously using SQL Server Management Studio 2012 with SQL Server 2008 running the T-SQL (on a production machine) that worked fine. I've now migrated to a local SQL Server Management Studio 2012 with SQL Server 2012 (for development) and the code that *used to work* doesn't anymore.

This code is what used to work: `SELECT * INTO [dbo].[Controls] FROM OpenDataSource('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'Data Source=C:\Show.mdb; Jet OLEDB:Database Password=BobSaget')...[Control]` The password has been obfuscated for security ...

That's likely a sloppy solution. What's the ideal way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what errors are you getting?  Do you have all your drivers installed?

Comment: Msg 7302, Level 16, State 1, Line 73
Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "MSDASC" for linked server "(null)".

Comment: What drivers might I be missing? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the drivers you need but if it works on one machine and not on the next, this may be the problem.

Comment: Oops, I also forgot to mention that in the same .SQL script I'm doing a lot of manipulation, like adding new tables, adding primary keys to tables that didn't have them, scrubbing some data ... That's another huge reason I want to stick with a .SQL script for it.

Comment: Start with SELECT *  FROM OpenDataSource('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'Data Source=C:\Show.mdb; Jet OLEDB:Database Password=BobSaget')...[Control] to see if it is a select or insert problem

Comment: @Blam, Error -- `Msg 7302, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "MSDASC" for linked server "(null)".` Thanks!

Comment: Look at drivers and config string.  You have you data in the root directory?

Comment: @Blam, I typically don't put my databases on the root of C:\, but I was testing and as such put it there. :P Didn't help though.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Microsoft's SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access.

> SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) is a free supported tool from Microsoft that simplifies database migration process from Access to SQL Server. SSMA for Access automates conversion of Microsoft Access database objects to SQL Server database objects, loads the objects into SQL Server, and then migrates data from Microsoft Access to SQL Server.
>
> SSMA for Access v5.2 is designed to support migration from Microsoft Access 97 and higher to all editions of SQL Server 2005, SQL Server 2008, SQL Server 2008 R2, SQL Server 2012, and SQL Azure.

You can find it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28763).

You may need to fix the structure after the migration as it tends to over exaggerate many of the data types.

Comment: Yes, I think you might have missed the part where I noted I wanted it to be a script-type solution. `Turn-Key` if you will. :P

Comment: @The1nk In my opinion, that is the **proper** way to import. You could set up an ODBC connection and write custom SQL.

Comment: Yeah. That may be the proper way. :( Basically, I'm writing this terrible application (feature creep caused it to bloat extensively, and a looming deadline is not allowing me to rewrite the infrastructure). I'm looking for a solution that's easy to delegate to a non-programmer, an end-user, to create new databases in the application. Using this tool would likely be difficult for him or her to manage.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your DCOM security on MSDAINITIALIZE?

I had this problem when moving to a local instance of SSMS 2012.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dataaccesstechnologies/archive/2011/09/28/troubleshooting-cannot-create-an-instance-of-ole-db-provider.aspx

Comment: Made all those changes.. Had to do the RegEdit note at the bottom to allow myself to edit them. Still no dice. I'll try a reboot and try again, to see maybe if the permissions didn't take hold yet. I'll update if it works. Thanks!